# Regex to match any string that should not contain / or \ and length between 2-60

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex to match any string that do not contain special characters `/` or `\`. I also want to keep the length of the string between 2 and 60 characters.

I haven't got any expertise with regex. So is there any way I can get a solution for my issue .

Comment: You can do this without regex. Actually you *should*.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I disagree. Actually `[^/\]{2,60}` does the trick

Comment: @Ploutox `[^/\\]{2,60}` actually. I don't know of an implementation where `\ ` inside a regex does not act as an escape character for `]`.

Comment: I have tried using ^[^\\/]*$ but its not working for me

Comment: @Stuborg "Not working" has no meaning. Not working **how**?

Comment: @Siguza Correct. I wrote the coment rapidly to talk about the idea. For completeness regarding OP's problem, he should also add delimiters like `^`, `$` or `\s` around this regex otherwise it will catch `foo` in `foo/` instead of rejecting the entry altogether

Comment: can you try this...[^\/\\]{2,60}

Comment: how about something like ^[A-Za-z0-9\d=!\-@._*]*$

Answer (score 0):

Escape both slashes try this:

```
[^\/\\]{2,60}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sC9gT5/1)